# How to Install Visual Editor on Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6, visual-editor

Hey, I use Eclipse Helios in Ubuntu, and I'd like to install a plugin for eclipse that works with swing. So, I found visual editor in this site http://www.eclipse.org/vep/downloads/, and I downloaded it.
Now, I'd like to know hoe to install it. I tryied going in Help>Install new Software, but nothing. So if someone could help me with this, i thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try WindowBuilder Pro?  Google released it as a free download after buying Instantiations.   http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed WindowBuilder Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the packaged plug-ins and features, you can unpackage it then copy them into the dropin folder of your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found [WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/wbpro/index.html) Pro as the better option...